# Checking certificate by x509Crl.IsRevoked() method in BouncyCastle library in C#?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509certificate, x509certificate2, certificate-revocation

I'm trying to check the certificate with its revocation list (crl-file). In BouncyCustle library there is a method `x509Crl.IsRevoked()`, that should be used for this. The point is that it gets `x509Certificate` object as a parameter, but I can't understand how to create this `x509Certificate` object.
I used `DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate()` for converting from `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.x509Certificate2` object to `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` object, but I faced the problem - method `IsRevoked()` always returns `true` - for all crl's I tested.

Question: how to create `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` object directly from binary without converting from `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.x509Certificate2`?

My code for checking certificate with it's crl-file:

```
static public void RevocationChecker(string certPath, string crlPath)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
        cert.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(certPath));
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bouncyCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);

        X509CrlParser crlParser = new X509CrlParser();
        X509Crl crl = crlParser.ReadCrl(File.ReadAllBytes(crlPath));

        bool rezult = crl.IsRevoked(bouncyCert);
        Console.WriteLine(rezult);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert = new System.Security
.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(File.ReadAllBytes(certPath));`    

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bouncyCert = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509
.X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - VS shows error CS0122 "Class is inaccessible due to its protection level" becouse Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() constructor is "protected"

Comment: @АлександрИльин updated the answer for clarification.

Comment: I tested your code - it works, but IsRevoced() method returns "true" as well. It should not return "true" - I converted the crl-file to txt-file and found no matches with my certificate serial number. I can't understand why the method returns "true"...

Comment: I extremely sorry - I tested your code on the wrong file! It works! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @АлександрИльин Glad to help! Please consider accepting the answer if you found it useful. :)